# Accessing a Pi connected to a router via windows

Tags: networking

novice question:
I have a RasPi 2, running Kodi, connected via Ethernet to my router.
I'd like to be able to access it through my windows laptop that's connected to the same network.
How do I do that?

Comment: There are half a dozen or so different ways of interacting with Kodi on a Pi. Can you describe what you're trying to do in any more detail? Are you trying to stream content from the Pi to the PC, or trying to send remote control commands from the PC to the Pi, or something completely different?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are attempting to access the files on your Raspberry Pi through your windows network. What you would likely need to do is turn on Samba on your PI, modify your firewall rules to make sure you aren't blocking access, and make the folders you want (likely the media folders) readable by all users.

The Kodi Wiki has a more detailed guide on how to do this in step by step fashion.
http://kodi.wiki/view/Samba

Comment: Thanks!
That's exactly what I want to do. I'll have a look at the guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SFTP protocol to access files on Kodi. Download an SFTP client, like [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), run it, enter the IP address of your device and port 22. More information: [Raspberry SSH](http://raspberry-pi-tutorial.com/enable-ssh-access-to-the-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: Thanks all. I'll have a look at all your suggestions. cheers!